# Plotting graph using matplotlib in Jupyter iPython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot graph using matplotlib in Jupyter python notebook. But when I am assigning y axis label, its not showing in the graph and also it's plotting two graphs. The code which I am using is :

```
trans_count_month = df.groupby('month_').TR_AMOUNT.count() 
plt.xlabel('Months')  #X-axis label
plt.ylabel('Total Transactions Count') #Y-axis label 
plt.title("Month wise Total Transaction Count") #Chart title. 
width = 9
height = 5
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
trans_count_month.plot(kind='bar')
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
```

and the output which I am getting is:
[image]

How I can show only one graph with y axis label also and if there is any other way to draw this graph please share the solution.

Comment: I would guess to just remove the first `plt.figure(figsize=width, height))`.

Comment: Try to change the order. The `plt.xlabel/ylable/title` should come after the `.plot`. Furthermore, use the `figsize` keyword argument of `plot` instead of `plt.figure(figsize=())`.

Comment: Thanks @Dror it's working now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

import pandas as pd

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a','b','c'])

s.plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
plt.xlabel('Foo')
plt.ylabel('Bar')
plt.title("Hello World");
```

[image]

Which better utilize pandas and matplotlib.